# GeoFence or distance calculation... what's the difference?

Tags: android

I read in the documentation that I can setup geofencing so I know when the user entered/left the geofenced area.

However, I was wondering, can't I get the same behaviour by just taking my current location (ona  regular location update) and check the distance with the center of the intended geofence. If it is less than a certain radius then I am within that area.

Wouldn't that have the same effect (infact way less code than geofence)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the advantage of a geofence as opposed to what you describe, is that geofences are objects that come with a lot of extra support in Google Play Services. Using geofences allows multiple different Activities or even Applications to get notifications/callbacks from a single (or set of) geofence objects created elsewhere. These callbacks will happen automatically even if you are in another application because Google Play Services can monitor location in the background without you writing additional code in your Activity, and they can expire on their own. Doing this would be more difficult if you were to roll your own distance calculations as you would have to set it up your own Service framework.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630926/android-why-use-pending-intents-for-geofences/16630963#16630963) by CommonsWare:

> Geofences are designed to work even without your application running.

However, if your goal is only to check whether you are a certain distance from a geographical point (without caring about what happens when the user goes to check their email or puts their phone back in their pocket), then what you describe might be easier.

Comment: Thank you BingsF for the answer. In my application, I already have location monitoring going on (supposely working when in background too) so I guess doing the distance thing might be easier than implementing framework

Comment: @Snakehow was your experience is this correct approach? I am also in the same direction and dont feel need to implementing geofencing